# android call without show dialing UI?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, telephony, telephonymanager

I am making an application that make call but I need a help to make the call without showing the Dialing interface, for example if I pressed on button call it will make the call but stay on the same location:

this is my application interface:

[image]

I don't need this dialing interface when pressing any button from my previous image what I need is to make a hidden call process:

[image]

Comment: got any solution ?

Answer (score -1):

Making a call in an Android dual SIM phone is tricky. There is not a single straightforward API that you can use to dial correctly from a SIM but if you have based your app on a single SIM device, the steps are simple -

Just make a new call intent and pass the number in it - 
For some devices, the dialler screen will open (you cannot avoid that) but for most of the devices it will start dialling with your activity in the background.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + number)); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```